# Using the substitution $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ to transform and evaluate the integral

Tags: integration

I was asked to prove the fact that
$$\int_{0}^a f(x)dx=\int_{0}^af(a-x)dx$$

The first part was quite easy to sort out by using the substitution $u=a-x$, but the second part of the question was to use the first part with $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$ to show that
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{\pi}{4}\sqrt{2}\ln(1+\sqrt{2})$$

Any help on this question is appreciated.

Comment: $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{\sin x+\cos x}=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{\sin x+\cos x}$ implies that $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{dx}{\sin x+\cos x}=0$. Should it be $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{xdx}{\sin x+\cos x}$?

Comment: btw there is a typo in your question, you are missing an "$x$" in the integrand (this is needed to get the answer you post)

Comment: Ah so the question does have a printing mistake then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, we can use substitution to prove that

$$ \int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(a + b  - x) dx  $$

Hence, if the problem is 
$$ I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x + \cos x} dx $$

then we have that

$$ I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x + \cos x} dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2} - x}{\sin (\frac{\pi}{2} - x) + \cos ( \frac{\pi}{2} - x}) dx 
= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2} - x}{\cos x + \sin x} dx  \\
= \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x} dx  - \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x + \cos x} dx $$

Therefore,

$$ I = \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x} dx   $$

Now, we need to evaluate $ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x} dx  $. We can do this by Wierstrass substitution: Pick $u = \tan(\frac{x}{2}) $ then $du = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2(\frac{x}{2}) dx $. Also note that from this step we have that: $\sin(x) = \frac{2u}{u^2 + 1}$ and $\cos(x) = \frac{1-u^2}{u^2 + 1} $. So therefore

$$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x} dx  = \int_0^1 \frac{2}{ (u^2 + 1) \bigg( \frac{2u}{u^2+1} + \frac{1-u^2}{u^2+1}  \bigg) } du = \int_0^1 \frac{2}{-u^2 + 2u + 1} du = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2 - (u-1)^2} du = \sqrt{2} \int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^0 \frac{1}{1 - s^2} ds = \sqrt{2} \tanh^{-1}\big(\frac{1}{2} \big) =  \sqrt{2}\ln(1 + \sqrt2 )  $$

Therefore,

$$ I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x + \cos x} dx = \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x} dx   = \frac{\pi}{4} \sqrt{2}\ln(1 + \sqrt2 ) $$